# Java - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11

Tags: java, string, exception, charat

I'm stuck with this and can't find a solution. Get error of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11.

Can anyone help to solve this?
My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Testing.txt"));
        int i = 0;

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            char needle = line.charAt(i);

            while(i < line.length()){
                if(Character.isUpperCase(needle)) {
                    while(needle != ' '){
                        System.out.print(needle);
                        i++;
                        needle = line.charAt(i);
                    }
                    System.out.println(needle);
                }
                else{
                    i++;
                    needle = line.charAt(i);
               }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the strings that contains capital letter from the input text file. E.g. input text file contains "Kenny and I are eating in the Restaurant Yummy.". The output will be "Kenny, I, Restaurant, Yummy".

Comment: use split to split your line into word and test the first char to see if starts with uppercase

Comment: Any examples that I can refer to? Thanks.

Comment: K.W I have added an answer showing you how.  Alot cleaner and easier to understand I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my above comment, it will be easuer to use the String `split` method.  Of course `input` can be replaced with text from the file, and use of `expectedResult` and testing that the output equals that is purely optional

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      String input = "Kenny and I are eating in the Restaurant Yummy";
      String expectedResult = "Kenny, I, Restaurant, Yummy";
      String arr [] = input.split (" ");

      StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (Character.isUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0))) {
              out.append(arr[i]).append(", ");
          }
      }

      if (out.length() > 1) {
          out.setLength(out.length() -2);
      }

      System.out.println (out);
      assert (expectedResult.equals(out.toString()));

  }
```

**output**

> > Kenny, I, Restaurant, Yummy

Comment: May I know what is this line do?

        if (out.length() > 1) {
          out.setLength(out.length() -2);
      }

Comment: because we are appending `", "` to every occurrence, we want to remove the last one.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that your error would be here;

```
                i++;
                needle = line.charAt(i);
```

and

```
                while(needle != ' '){
                    System.out.print(needle);
                    i++;
                    needle = line.charAt(i);
                }
```

As you are increasing the index without checking if the index exists.

Comment: Any idea of how to fix this? How to check whether if the index is exists from the above code?

Comment: Something like if(i < line.length()), as you have elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. But from your error, I can say that you are trying to increment the index counter and then trying to access the element in your String.

Inside your `while` loop and the `else` block, you have these statements:

```
i++;
needle = line.charAt(i);
```

Change them both to:

```
needle = line.charAt(i);
i++;
```

And your code will run without the said exception.

> **Update**

I did the changes mentioned above, and made a couple of changes.

1. Include the declaration for `int i=0;` inside the first while loop. This is needed for more than one line in the text file.
2. Include the declaration `char needle = line.charAt(i);` statement inside the second while loop as you need to initialize needle for each line.

---

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Testing.txt"))) {

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < line.length()) {
            char needle = line.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(needle)) {
                while (needle != ' ' && i < line.length()) {
                    needle = line.charAt(i);
                    if(needle != ' '){
                        System.out.print(needle);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(i < line.length()) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
            } else {
                needle = line.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

---

It prints the following output:

```
Kenny, I, Restaurant, Yummy
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to get all the strings that contains capital letter from the input text file. E.g. input text file contains "Kenny and I are eating in the Restaurant Yummy.". The output will be "Kenny, I, Restaurant, Yummy". I have try to change them both according to the solution you suggest, but still getting the same error.